# Is it possible to query the first 5 images with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, dom

Is it possible to query the first 5 images with DOMDocument?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
       $list = $dom->query('img');
```

Comment: @jack Using xpath how do I do that? I am new to this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`XPath`](http://php.net/domxpath) You can fetch all images like this:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$list = $xpath->query('//img');
```

Then you limit the results by only iterating over the first five.

```
for ($i = 0, $n = min(5, $list->length); $i < $n; ++$i) {
    $node = $list->item(0);
}
```

XPath is very versatile thanks to its [expression language](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). However, in this particular case, you may not need all that power and a simple `$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')` would yield the same result set.

Comment: Awesome hack with `min(5, $list->length)` !

Comment: @jQuery00 How is that a "hack"? It's more like "good programming practice".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes! Simply I'm not good in english and sometimes incorrectly express my thoughts

Comment: @JonathonReinhart - "hack" original meant a clever programming solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to build and array of images:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$result = array();
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++){
    $node = $images->item($i);
    if (is_object( $node)){
        $result[] = $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
    }
}
```